# Colocar variáveis no URL em MVC para usar com JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax, razor

Tenho uma página de pesquisa que vai buscar os resultados usando ajax. Faça as pesquisas que fizer, o URL é sempre igual, pois a página não muda. Há alguma maneira para eu puder mudar o URL também quando faço a pesquisa? Ex: queria ter uma variável que guardasse a keyword da pesquisa no URL para depois eu puder busca-la numa função javascript. Vai ser preciso mudar o routing do controller em questão? Trabalho com MVC4 e RazorView, e uso JS para implementar o ajax.

Chamo este método para pesquisar (Material/Index):

```
public ActionResult Index(Portal.Models.MaterialsAdvancedSearchViewModel advancedFilter, string searchParameter, bool chooseMaterialsSpotlight = false)
    {...}
```

Quando pesquisar alguma coisa ele vai correr este método (Material/MaterialPagination):

```
public ActionResult MaterialPagination(int page, int results, string searchParameter, string order_field,
        string order_by, Portal.Models.MaterialsAdvancedSearchViewModel advancedFilter,
        string companyID, bool chooseMaterialsSpotlight = false)
    {...}
```

Neste segundo método ele vai buscar todos os materiais que eu tenho da base de dados que correspondem aos filtros (os argumentos de entrada) e coloca-los numa partial view que é carregada usando ajax para a view do primeiro método. Eu queria de alguma maneira colocar no URL esses filtros para puder fazer uma pesquisa só com o URL. Eu neste momento não consigo ir diretamente à página 5, e se eu clicar em algum resultado de pesquisa ele abre uma nova janela, eu queria puder abrir na mesma janela para depois retroceder e ficar onde estava na pesquisa.

Comment: Pelo que você diz, basicamente é só mudar o verbo da action pra **`GET`**. Mas sem muito detalhes e sem um exemplo em código fica complicado de te ajudar.

Comment: @jbueno eu tentei passar a informação que achei essencial, mas se precisar de mais algum detalhe eu vou estar atento.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver esta situação usando a History API do HTML5. Para quem ainda não conhece pode dar uma olhada no site da mozzila [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).